# "save this stack" doesn't work in livecode

Tags: mobile, stack, save, livecode

Once I could save an existing state in the application using the "save this stack" command, both on a computer and on a mobile device.

Today I found out, it no longer works.
For example: there is a field that is incremented by 1, and I reach 10.

If I leave the app and reopen it, it's not saved and will start from 0.

Why? How can this be fixed?

Code:

```js
on mouseDown
add 1 to field "counter"
save this stack
end mouseDown
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a new stack with a field and a button, and place this in the button script:

```
 on mouseUp
  add 1 to fld 1
  save this stack
end mouseUp
```

If you click on the button, the field increments. If you then close the stack, it will shut down at once, not asking if you want to save it. If you then re-open, the last state of the field is displayed.

The reason you are not asked to save is because the stack was just saved, and no changes were made. The field holds the latest value. In other words, all is right with the world. The question then becomes this: what is different about your stack?

Mac os 10.9. LC 8.1.8. (But none of any of that should matter)

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what I did But it is not saved! I pressed and pressed And I got to 10. Then I closed the app and reopened it The field presented the first value (0 for this purpose) and not the value 10 * Not working on mobile

Answer (score 0):

Desktop: I tried it on my IDE and it works! But only if you use is as  livecode stack and not as standalone, see next section.

Mobile: You can not save changes in the main stack on mobile devices because it is always a standalone. Mainstacks in standalones cannot be chanched because they are part of the binary. If you want to have a stack on a mobile device (or desktop) which can save itself you have to create it as a substack.

Answer (score 0):

To be correct, a substack, if also part of the executable file, cannot be saved.

The usual method is to attach one or more stack files to a "Splash" stack.

The Splash stack generally has limited functionality, such as to navigate to the working stack or stacks, and all their substacks. Those all can be saved. The splash stack is simply a vehicle to open the standalone, and then let its associated stacks do the real work.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
command saveThisStack
   put fld "score" of cd "mainCard" into tTempList
   put the base64Encode of tTempList into tTempList
   set the defaultFolder to specialFolderPath("documents")
   put  tTempList into URL ("file:score.txt")
end saveThisStack
```